# Creating a chart with Bluemix Embedded Reporting

Tags: charts, ibm-cloud, cognos-bi

Using IBM Bluemix I created an app, a Cloudant NoSQL DB, a dashDB and an Embeddable Reporting service.   In dashDB I created a table with a couple of columns and some simple data.  Next I configured the Embeddable Reporting service and pointed it to the Cloudant DB for its own storage and dashDB for reporting data.  Next I open Report Studio and create a chart mapping in some data:

[image]

When I play the report page, I get an indication that I have not supplied data:

[image]

However if I create a different report and ask for a List ...

[image]

The list appears just fine ...

[image]

I am at a loss to understand why my chart will not appear but my list will.  I will be happy to amend and update my question with any relevant information anyone may need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine a vertical column chart.  Now imagine data of the form:

`Dallas        10
New York      30
San Francisco 50`

We can easily imagine the cities on the X-Axis and the values on the Y-Axis.  This is easy enough.  But now imagine that our X-Axis rows in our data are not unique ... for example:

`West-Region  10
East-Region  30
West-Region  20`

What then should the "value" of the `West-Region` column be?  The column names should be unique and hence we can't have two columns with the same name.  Should the value of the `West-Region` be 30 (the sum) or 15 (the average) or something else?

And that is where the problem comes in.  When we define a column in a chart, there is no defined `Aggregate Function`.  What we need to do is define how we want values to be aggregated together.  If we select the column and select its properties, we can find an `Aggregate Function` option.  We can choose a function such as `Average`.

Once defined, the chart will show up correctly because it can now properly handle aggregation.   Now, this might seem strange especially if we know for certain that there is never a need for aggregation because values are unique ... but apparently, these are the rules (for better or worse) and, once set, charts now show:

[image]